# How can I get top visited pages of a site?

Tags: curl, web-crawler

I need to get most visited pages of a site.Like top 20 pages of example.com.
Is there any api or something else to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the site. It must have some sort of visitor statistics tracking, such as Google Analytics. This tracking software must provide an API, and you must have the privileges to access it, which is usually only if you are running the site yourself or have been granted the necessary privileges by the site owner.

Another way, if you have direct access to the web server, would involve analyzing the web server logs.

Please clarify if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: No dude , its just another third party site & I dont want to crawl whole of it.Just need some top pages.

Comment: You won't get that information unless the owner of the site makes it available to you. Crawling the site won't help either, since it doesn't provide any information on the popularity of certain parts of the site.